# Load two custom libraries

Tags: php, composer-php

I have some problem by using Composer to load a custom library from another custom library

---

I have 2 custom libraries called "ia/audit_trail" and "ia/flash". And "ia/audit_trail" needs "ia/flash" to work.

> audit_trail : https://github.com/pierrererot/audit_trail
>
> flash : https://github.com/pierrererot/flash

So, I have the require property set for calling another one. Nothing special, BUT, when I run a simple `composer update -vvv` in my main project, I got this error :

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>    Problem 1
>      - Installation request for ia/audit_trail_component ~1.0.0 -> satisfiable by ia/audit_trail_component[1.0.0].
>      - ia/audit_trail_component 1.0.0 requires ia/flash_component ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>   - A typo in the package name
>   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>     see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
>   - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems...

BUT, if I put these two librairies directly into my main project (so if one librairy doesn't need another librairy), it works !.

---

Here is the `composer.json` of my main project :

```
{
    "require": {
        "ia/audit_trail_component": "1.0.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/pierrererot/audit_trail.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

All right. So I did require my custom "audit_trail" library. So now, here is the `composer.json` of my custom "audit_trail" library :

```
{
    "name": "ia/audit_trail_component",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "ia/flash_component": "1.0.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/pierrererot/flash.git"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

All right. So I did require my custom "flash" library. And then, here is the `composer.json` of my custom "flash" library :

```
{
    "name": "ia/flash_component",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Flash Component",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

As you can see, everything seems ok in my composer files, so I don't understand what I missed.

### ==> Does anyone have a clue please ?

Before you ask, I precise these things :

- Both libraries have a "dev" and a "master" branch pushed on their Git repositories
- Both libraries have a minimum 1.0.0 tag pushed on their Git repositories

Comment: you have to declare them on https://packagist.org/ (which is the registry for composer, ie the database of the public packages) . Putting it on github doesn't make it available for composer until you register it on packagist.

Comment: if these are private packages, you have to add another field to indicate the url of the repos.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository if you don't register them on packagist, should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I did add a field to indicate the URL of the repos. Look at the URL properties into both composer.json files.

Comment: PS : I edited my topic, because it looks like a dependecy issue. I added this paragraph :

"BUT, if I put these two librairies directly into my main project (so if one librairy doesn't need another librairy), it works !."

Comment: use semver, when writing `1.0.0` you are requiring an exact version of your package, which corresponds to an exact commit. With `~1.0.0` or `^1.0.0` you may fetch last versions.

Comment: Nice idea, but it shouldn't be relevant because 1.0.0 is the exact version of my package. I tried it anyway with ^1.0.0, but I have the same message error. 

"ia/audit_trail_component 1.0.0 requires ia/flash_component ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found."


Notice that I don't have the problem if I put the "Flash" library directly into my main composer.json project (not into the "Audit_trail" librairy). 

I created a test here if you wanna lock at it or clone it to test : https://github.com/pierrererot/test.git

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`repositories` setting is root-only - Composer will ignore this setting for all dependencies and use only these repositories defined in your main project.

> Repositories are only available to the root package and the repositories defined in your dependencies will not be loaded. Read the [FAQ entry](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can't-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md) if you want to learn why.
>
> <sub>https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#repository</sub>

So you need add all necessary repositories into `composer.json` of your main project:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/pierrererot/audit_trail.git"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/pierrererot/flash.git"
    }
],
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I see. Absolutely. You are right. I just tried it btw and your solution works, thanks a lot. I'll try to find a way to make it more agreable. Thanks again !

Comment: @Raken_887 If your package is public, you should use packagist, so you wouldn't need "repositories". If you don't, you should try a private registry for composer (private packagist is not free).

Comment: I will ! :)
Thanks again, both of you ! :) It helped me a lot