# Composer custom GitLab server dependencies

Tags: php, package, gitlab, composer-php, repository

We have a company GitLab server behind a VPN. Packages in there are set as being public, but they are de facto "private" since you can't get to repository without authorizing on our VPN.

I made one repository which has dependency to other (on the same server).

Repo 1:

```
"name": "xxx/repo1",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://pvt/repo2"
    }
],
"require": {
    "xxx/repo2": "dev-master"
},
```

Repo 2:

```
"name": "xxx/repo2"
```

The issue I'm getting is when I try to use `repo1` in one of my other services.

```
"name": "other/service",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://pvt/repo1"
    }
],
"require": {
    "xxx/repo1": "dev-master"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

Doing a `composer install` like this just tells me that `repo2` can't be found. I can solve it like this:

```
"name": "other/service",
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://pvt/repo1"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "http://pvt/repo2"
    }
],
"require": {
    "xxx/repo1": "dev-master"
},
```

But this is far from ideal. If I have 10 services and all need `repo1` to run, introducing a new dependency inside `repo1` would require me to change 10 `composer.json` files.

Why doesn't this function the same way as with other dependencies, so that all required dependencies of the requested package are pulled automatically?

I tried adding this to config:

```
"config": {
    "gitlab-domains": [
        "pvt"
    ],
    "gitlab-token": {
        "pvt" : "---my-token---"
    }
},
```

But this did nothing basically.

I also tried replacing `pvt` with exact server IP, but nothing changed.

Is there a way to make this work?

Note: I do not want to use any external service like Private Packagist or Satis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load two custom libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462497/load-two-custom-libraries)

Comment: Well as I said, I already do have that solution. But it doesn't suit me to have it like that since I will need to update multiple json files in case I add a new dependency to `repo1`

Comment: This is how Composer works. If you want to use private repositories, you may want to take a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md, but you will still need to add private repository in every package, since repositories are not inherited from dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this work?

The answer is "no" - see the official Composer's explanation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 13.2 (July 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/07/22/gitlab-13-2-released/#manage-php-dependencies-with-the-gitlab-composer-repository) offers an alternative

> ### Manage PHP dependencies with the GitLab Composer Repository

> PHP developers need a mechanism to share and consume their projects’ dependencies. Composer is a dependency manager for PHP that allows you to declare the libraries your project depends on and it will manage them for you.
>
> We are proud to offer a Composer Repository built directly into GitLab.
>
> PHP Developers now have an easier way to discover and manage their projects’ dependencies. By integrating with Composer, GitLab provides a centralized location to view those packages in the same place as source code and pipelines. PHP dependencies in the Package Registry will be listed under the All tab and not under a Composer-specific tab. We will iterate to improve this by adding a Composer-specific tab in an upcoming milestone.

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15886)