# How to use private composer package inside another private composer package?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have 2 composer packages I created and I want to use the first package inside the second package, and I want to use the second package in my main app.

Now when I run `composer update` my main app can see the 2nd package, but 2nd package can't see the first package.

The error im getting is:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for mycompany/package1 dev-branch1 -> satisfiable by
>   mycompany/package1[dev-branch1].
> - mycompany/package1 dev-branch1 requires mycompany/package2 dev-master -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
> - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
> further common problems.

But when I run `composer install` in the 2nd package there is no problem and it installs the 1st package to 2nd package.

So is there a way to install a package, which is dependent to another custom package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load two custom libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54462497/load-two-custom-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the 2nd package directly on the main project does it install? Composer cannot chain load dependencies on its own as described here.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md

Like the documentation says, in case of private packages, you must use Satis or a private Packagist instance for this use case